# Is there a way to change the output volume of any sound that comes from your site?

Tags: javascript

This may sound weird even to me but whatever, I'll ask it and get it done with.

I was wondering if there is any way to alter the output volume of all noisy stuff of your site or of a particular element. I'll appreciate any info about it, like for example a third party plugin, whether is technically impossible or whatever.

I tagged it as javascript because I have no idea what to tag it with.

Thanks

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407002/how-to-control-the-system-volume-using-javascript

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are asking? Are you looking to control sounds of an existing web page with existing sounds? Or are you developing a web page from scratch? If from scratch, you could use buzz.js to play back (and control volume of) audio: http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide an easy solution, but I can provide some info.  Check out https://github.com/jussi-kalliokoski/audiolib.js for a HTML5/javascript audio library.  The guys at ofmlabs.org live and breathe this stuff.